# How do I write a maven plugin which actually runs?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The instructions here seem very clear:

```
http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html
```

However, the first problem I run into is that the dependencies are wrong. I also needed to reference the maven-plugin-annotations dependency.

Then, when I attempt to run I get the "No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml" error. I haven't figured out what to do about that.

I've found lots of pages referencing the maven-plugin-plugin, but I can't figure out how to add it to the pom so that it actually does anything which allows my own plugin to run.

Is there an updated version of the plugin development instructions which actually mentions the need to use maven-plugin-plugin?

If I can't get this to work I'm just going to go back to using exec-maven-plugin. It's uglier, but at least it works easily.

Comment: Can you show the pom? You can start with [this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/Maven-Echo-Plugin/blob/master/pom.xml) as reference.

Comment: I have the problem as well following the the tutorial, getting `Error extracting plugin descriptor: 'No mojo definitions were found for plugin: com.myplugin`

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several terrific resources from Sonatype for learning how to write plugins:

- [Maven the Complete Reference: Writing Plugins](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins.html)
- [Maven Cookbook: Creating an Ant Maven Plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/reference/ch04s04.html)
- [Maven Cookbook: Writing Plugins in Groovy](http://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/reference/writing-plugins-alternative-sect-writing-groovy.html)

Comment: A more up-to-date source for information about that topic is at http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you need to configure the *maven-plugin-plugin* this way to avoid the "*No plugin descriptor found...*" issue.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5346 -->
          <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
          <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions> 
</plugin>
```

I forked a simple GitHub project called [maven-wrapper](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/maven-wrapper) (port of the [Gradle wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)) to make it a Maven plugin.

"It should be easy" for you to figure out pieces that you may eventually be missing:

- [Maven wrapper plugin(Mojo)](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/maven-wrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wrapper/MavenWrapperMojo.java)
- [Maven Wrapper full POM](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/maven-wrapper/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: after adding your example xml into my `pom.xml` I stopped getting `Error extracting plugin descriptor: 'No mojo definitions were found for plugin: com.myplugin` and started getting `Compilation error: ... error: package org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations does not exist` which seems to be better :)

Comment: Just needed to add dependency on: `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope><!-- annotations are needed only to build the plugin -->
    </dependency>`